# JavaScript Regular Expression Find and Replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check if a string contains the following string, "Password:". If so I want to replace the word immediately following the ':'. For example, I have a string that has "Password:Test". I would like "Test" removed and replaced with "Removed".

Comment: Ok. So where are you stuck? What have you got so far? What's the question?

Comment: is the string only password:<something> or just part of the string

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following (**please see edit if this doesn't work in your browser**):

```js
var input = 'Password:Test'

console.log(input.replace(/(?<=Password:).+/, 'Removed'));
```

#### Edit

As @ctwheels pointed, lookbehinds have little support in JavaScript ([see the current stage of the TC39 proposal here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind)). At the time of writing this only Chrome (starting with version 62) and Moddable (after Jan 17, 2018) support lookbehinds in JavaScript. Use the following instead:

**Regex**: `(Password:).+` **Substitution**: `$1Removed`

```js
var input = 'Password:Test'

console.log(input.replace(/(Password:).+/, '$1Removed'));
```

Comment: Careful, JavaScript lookbehind support is very low. I believe (at the moment) only Chrome 62+ supports this.

Comment: @ctwheels Updated!

Comment: I updated your question to include all relevant information as of right now.

Answer (score 0):

This works Run code:

```js
var string = "Passoword:Test";
var find = string.indexOf(":");
var newstring = string.substr(0,find) + ":" + "Removed";

console.log(newstring);
```